# My DNS Server cannot find a website when asked by my computer but it can when asked by another

Tags: windows, windows-10, dns

I suppose the title really says it all... that being said, I get the following results from my computer...

***EDIT 1 - Additional Details -***

***--------------------------------------------------------------------***

I accessed the landing page after creating the domain which I was able to get to, then I set up the AWS environment including setting up my Route53 Alias Record pointing to my static page within my S3 Bucket... After creating the Alias record and updating the DNS NS records with my registrar.  Everything should work, and it does!! with everything except my computer...

***--------------------------------------------------------------------***

```
> nslookup -debug procyclinsur.pro
------------
Got answer:
    HEADER:
        opcode = QUERY, id = 1, rcode = NOERROR
        header flags:  response, want recursion, recursion avail.
        questions = 1,  answers = 1,  authority records = 3,  additional = 3

    QUESTIONS:
        97.112.122.61.in-addr.arpa, type = PTR, class = IN
    ANSWERS:
    ->  97.112.122.61.in-addr.arpa
        name = wtk-ns03.fttx.co.jp
        ttl = 7501 (2 hours 5 mins 1 sec)
    AUTHORITY RECORDS:
    ->  112.122.61.in-addr.arpa
        nameserver = ns03.usen.ad.jp
        ttl = 7501 (2 hours 5 mins 1 sec)
    ->  112.122.61.in-addr.arpa
        nameserver = ns01.usen.ad.jp
        ttl = 7501 (2 hours 5 mins 1 sec)
    ->  112.122.61.in-addr.arpa
        nameserver = ns02.usen.ad.jp
        ttl = 7501 (2 hours 5 mins 1 sec)
    ADDITIONAL RECORDS:
    ->  ns01.usen.ad.jp
        internet address = 61.122.116.130
        ttl = 29182 (8 hours 6 mins 22 secs)
    ->  ns02.usen.ad.jp
        internet address = 61.122.116.162
        ttl = 29182 (8 hours 6 mins 22 secs)
    ->  ns03.usen.ad.jp
        internet address = 61.122.116.163
        ttl = 29123 (8 hours 5 mins 23 secs)

------------
サーバー:  wtk-ns03.fttx.co.jp
Address:  61.122.112.97

------------
Got answer:
    HEADER:
        opcode = QUERY, id = 2, rcode = NXDOMAIN
        header flags:  response, want recursion, recursion avail.
        questions = 1,  answers = 0,  authority records = 1,  additional = 0

    QUESTIONS:
        procyclinsur.pro.ps.local, type = A, class = IN
    AUTHORITY RECORDS:
    ->  (root)
        ttl = 6520 (1 hour 48 mins 40 secs)
        primary name server = a.root-servers.net
        responsible mail addr = nstld.verisign-grs.com
        serial  = 2016121200
        refresh = 1800 (30 mins)
        retry   = 900 (15 mins)
        expire  = 604800 (7 days)
        default TTL = 86400 (1 day)

------------
------------
Got answer:
    HEADER:
        opcode = QUERY, id = 3, rcode = NXDOMAIN
        header flags:  response, want recursion, recursion avail.
        questions = 1,  answers = 0,  authority records = 1,  additional = 0

    QUESTIONS:
        procyclinsur.pro.ps.local, type = AAAA, class = IN
    AUTHORITY RECORDS:
    ->  (root)
        ttl = 6520 (1 hour 48 mins 40 secs)
        primary name server = a.root-servers.net
        responsible mail addr = nstld.verisign-grs.com
        serial  = 2016121200
        refresh = 1800 (30 mins)
        retry   = 900 (15 mins)
        expire  = 604800 (7 days)
        default TTL = 86400 (1 day)

------------
------------
Got answer:
    HEADER:
        opcode = QUERY, id = 4, rcode = SERVFAIL
        header flags:  response, want recursion, recursion avail.
        questions = 1,  answers = 0,  authority records = 0,  additional = 0

    QUESTIONS:
        procyclinsur.pro, type = A, class = IN

------------
------------
Got answer:
    HEADER:
        opcode = QUERY, id = 5, rcode = SERVFAIL
        header flags:  response, want recursion, recursion avail.
        questions = 1,  answers = 0,  authority records = 0,  additional = 0

    QUESTIONS:
        procyclinsur.pro, type = AAAA, class = IN

------------
*** wtk-ns03.fttx.co.jp が procyclinsur.pro を見つけられません: Server failed
```

while getting a separate set of results from another server. or even my phone...

```
$ dig procyclinsur.pro

; <<>> DiG 9.9.4-RedHat-9.9.4-29.el7_2.4 <<>> procyclinsur.pro
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 26660
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;procyclinsur.pro.              IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
procyclinsur.pro.       5       IN      A       52.219.0.6

;; Query time: 161 msec
;; SERVER: 12.0.0.2#53(12.0.0.2)
;; WHEN: Mon Dec 12 11:53:39 UTC 2016
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 61
```

I have checked my host files, I have flushed my browser caches, my dns caches, reset my internet connection... restarted my computer... however I have not had any success reaching my website.. (not much of a site at the moment)

I would be highly grateful for anyone's help in resolving this issue...

***EDIT: 2 - Additional Information -***

***--------------------------------------------------------------------***

I was able to access the site soon after making this post by utilizing Google's DNS server (8.8.8.8), however switching back to my DNS Server I was yet again unable to access the site.

Additionally my co-worker was able to access the site from the very same DNS server from which I could not!!?

***--------------------------------------------------------------------***

***EDIT: 1 - Potential Conclusion???? -***

***--------------------------------------------------------------------***

So, What I am assuming happened was that my DNS Server `61.122.112.97` was caching my previous connection to the domain landing page that I went to for the TTL of the record.  However, if it were truly my DNS server doing this... I would suspect that everyone else using that DNS server would get the same results.  Do DNS server's Cache connections on a per user basis????

PS - I was able to get to the page this morning from my computer... could it really be a cache issue on the DNS Server side??

***--------------------------------------------------------------------***

Comment: You haven't showed that it is in fact the _same_ DNS server being queried. Is the Windows system actually using 12.0.0.2? What does `nslookup -debug procyclinsur.pro. 12.0.0.2` return?

Comment: No, you are right, I have not shown that, what is being shown currently is a different DNS server, however my coworker can access the URL from the same network using the same 61.122.112.97 DNS Server that my Windows machine is using.

`nslookup -debug procyclinsur.pro. 12.0.0.2` will not actually work, as although it doesn't follow standard RFC 1918 conventions regarding private address ranges, it is a private subnet within an AWS VPC and is separate from the network that I am on.

Comment: In that case it's probably a problem with AWS specifically.

Comment: If it was an issue with AWS I would find it hard to believe that anyone can access the site. I am leaning towards my ***EDIT: 1*** in which I mention that it might have been my DNS server.  I am wondering if anyone can confirm local caching per client (machine) for DNS servers.  Also if you read the text I added up near the top of my post I accessed the landing page for my domain before switching the domain over to my site.

Comment: I should probably add that I was able to access it from my computer by utilizing Google's DNS (8.8.8.8) so it can't be DNS as a whole or files locally on my computer.